# LWC audio / blob component

Tags: lightning-web-components, blob, js

I have a LWC component and Apex Method, my apex method return a blob element from API response(my API response is a MP3 audio), how can I use this blob element on JS to add in HTML audio element??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Apex** method should return **String** ( base-64 encoding Blob)  instead of **Blob** .

After that you need to **decode** base-64 string back to **Blob** in your **LWC**.
Please take a look on this question : [Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

So your solution will look like this :

**Apex Class** :

```java
public with sharing class PlayAudioFromBlobController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getAudioBlobContent(){
        try {
            // Your logic which gets Blob
            Blob audioBlob;
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(audioBlob);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**LWC JS file**:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
// import Apex method from LWC
import getAudioBlobContent from '@salesforce/apex/PlayAudioFromBlobController.getAudioBlobContent'; 
    
export default class PlayAudioFromBlob extends LightningElement {
    // some other LWC logic

    // JS method on which we call Apex method and play audio 
    async playAudioFromBlob(){
        // helper JS function for Decodindg base64Data to BLOB
        const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
            const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
            const byteArrays = [];
            for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
                const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
                const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
                byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            }
            const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
            return blob;
        }
        // calling Apex method from LWC
        await getAudioBlobContent().then( (base64Data) => {
            const contentType = 'audio/mpeg'; // content type for audio/mp3
            const blob = b64toBlob(base64Data, contentType);
            
            // simple example how we can use audio in LWC
            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // if you do not need to play it, change any logic from here
            let audioElement = new Audio( audioUrl );
            audioElement.play();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }
}
```

In case that you do **NOT** need to **play** the audio,
You should change the last two lines of `playAudioFromBlob` method to your wishes.